# How to search store with multiple index keys?

Tags: ydn-db

I've a store with multiple keys (createdat, txdate).  They are separate keys not compound key.  I want to search data for all data of createdat='06/01/2014' and txdate between '06/01/2014' and '06/30/2014'

Can anyone help me how to do this query in ydn?

Answer (score 0):

No, you have to use compound key of `[createdat, txdate]`.

However, if you want to do very slow in-memroy filtering, you can iterate `txdate` and filter out createdat.